# upgrade compact framework version in htc phones?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, upgrade

hi i want to upgrade the version of compact framework in my htc touch phone. I am doing these steps

1. i have downdloaded the framework msi.
2. connected the phone through WMDC to the computer.
3. i copied the msi to MyDocuments.
4. from my phone i browsed to the my documents and clicked the msi.

Woof the system says "There is no application associated with "NETCFSetupv35", Run the application first, then open this file from within the application."

But when i try to run the application it just shows the message to quit the application and upgrade the framework version

I m just stuck in this loop please somebody help me to get out of this loop.

Regards,

Madhup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install the framework on the device then use the .cab file instead. These are usually stored somewhere like:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE

These can be installed manually on the device by clicking or via some code running on the device.

Answer (score 4):

I think this will solve your problem: Run that MSI file from your desktop while the HTC device is connected via ActiveSync. Your mobile device was never meant to run MSI files, that's the desktop's job. :-)

Comment: hi do i have to copy the msi to the device,s file system or simply run the file from the desktop?

Comment: Simply run the MSI from your desktop. ActiveSync will take care of transferring files to the device as needed.